# Display image over image CSS (2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

After posting the question:
[Display image over image css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483437/display-image-over-image-css/23485315)

I didn't solve the problem yet, but I will give you some updates that I came up with.

Look at this picture you will understand what i really want to do:
[image: http://www.shy22.com/upfiljpg/nac74671.jpg]

I need that red box go to that green spot.

When I try to change that hover box to `position:absolute` it becomes like this:
[image: http://www.shy22.com/upfiljpg/bth74604.jpg]

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid-wrap">
    <div class="grid">
        <figure data-scroll-reveal="enter left and move 50px over 2.13s">
            <img src="img/latest-work/1-1.jpg" alt="img01" />
            <img src="img/hover.png" class="hover-img" />
        </figure>
        <figure data-scroll-reveal="enter left and move 50px over 1.73s">
            <img src="img/latest-work/2-2.jpg" alt="img05" />
        </figure>
        <figure data-scroll-reveal="enter left and move 50px over 1.33s">
            <img src="img/latest-work/3-3.jpg" alt="img08" />
        </figure>
        <figure data-scroll-reveal="enter left and move 50px over 2.13s">
            <img src="img/latest-work/4-4.jpg" alt="img02" />
        </figure>
        <figure data-scroll-reveal="enter left and move 50px over 1.73s">
            <img src="img/latest-work/5-5.jpg" alt="img04" />
        </figure>
        <figure data-scroll-reveal="enter left and move 50px over 1.33s">
            <img src="img/latest-work/6-6.jpg" alt="img03" />
        </figure>
        <figure data-scroll-reveal="enter left and move 50px over 2.13s">
            <img src="img/latest-work/7-7.jpg" alt="img09" />
        </figure>
        <figure data-scroll-reveal="enter left and move 50px over 1.73s">
            <img src="img/latest-work/8-8.jpg" alt="img06" />
        </figure>
        <figure data-scroll-reveal="enter left and move 50px over 1.33s">
            <img src="img/latest-work/9-9.jpg" alt="img07" />
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /grid-wrap -->
```

**CSS**

```
.grid-wrap {
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-perspective: 1500px;
    perspective: 1500px;
}
.grid {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.25, 1);
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.25, 1);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    text-align: center;
}
.grid figure, .grid .placeholder {
    width: 340px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.grid figure {
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.grid figure {
    background-color: black;
}
.grid figure img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.grid figure img.hover-img {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: please include a working fiddle in your question : http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need something like this

```
 <div class="parent">
     <img src="" class="child1">//this image will be placed above the below one
     <img src="" class="child2">
 </div>

 .parent{
         width:100px;
         height:100px;
         display:block;
         position relative;//this is important
        }
 .child1{
         width:100px;
         height:100px;
         position:absolute;//this will place the image with class ".child1" over the image with class "child2"
         display:block;
        }
  .child2{
          width:100px;
          height:100px;
          position relative;//this is not so important
          display:block;
         }
```

this should achieve what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, no need for the hover image, I replaced it with pseudo element:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="grid-wrap">
    <div class="grid">
        <figure data-scroll-reveal="enter left and move 50px over 2.13s">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200.jpg" alt="img01" />
        </figure>
        <figure data-scroll-reveal="enter left and move 50px over 1.73s">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200.jpg" alt="img05" />
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.grid-wrap {
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-perspective: 1500px;
    perspective: 1500px;
}
.grid {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.25, 1);
    transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.25, 1);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    text-align: center;
}
.grid figure, .grid .placeholder {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.grid figure {
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.grid figure {
    background-color: black;
}
.grid-img {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
figure:after {
    display:none;
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url('http://soluciones.infonova.es/Portals/2/RECURSOS/GestionIntegral/Asesoramiento/seleccion.png') no-repeat;
    opacity:.5;
    border:1px solid red;
}
figure:hover:after {
    display:inline;
}
```

And here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KarimAG/ZnprJ/1/)**.

Comment: Thanks you , i've allready solved this with the help of Mr.coder
But thank you this would fix the problem too !

Answer (score 0):

I would be more inclined to go with a pseduo-element than an image in the HTML

**Basic HTML**

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-200-200-6.jpg" />
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure {
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

figure:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;    
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    background-size: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    transition:all .25s ease;  
}

figure:hover:after {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    background-image: url(http://iconbug.com/data/59/128/073a9e305ecf2fd8a953db5d5db2881f.png);
}

figure img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rzd6G/)

Comment: Thanks you , i've allready solved this with the help of Mr.coder
But thank you this would fix the problem too !